# Firebase - Use 3rd party email service for all emails

Tags: email, firebase

There are a number of examples of using a Firebase Cloud Function that triggers on user creation or deletion (see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions)) to send an email (potentially using a 3rd party service).

I'm looking for a way to send *Email address verification*, *Password reset* and *Email address change* messages through a 3rd party email service as well.

Is it possible to either configure that in Firebase's console, or can the default action of sending these messages through Google's own email service be disabled and some Firebase Cloud Function trigger be used to replace that functionality with a 3rd party email service?

Comment: Nope, you can't do that.  You can always file a feature request with an explanation of why it's important for you to be able to send mail like that.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: @DougStevenson Hmm that's a shame. Is there any way to manually generate an `actionCode` as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) in a Firebase Cloud Function so I can essentially re-create my own password reset flow?

Comment: That page documents how you can respond to actions the user is taking. You can't hijack the process and take it over for yourself.

Comment: I am also looking for same thing